# Como evitar que o Hibernate crie as colunas a partir dos campos de uma classe mãe abstrata

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tenho uma classe abstrata `Pessoas` com métodos `getters` e `setters` e uma classe concreta que herda de `Pessoas` (membros). Ao mapear a classe concreta como entity e seus campos, ela está criando as colunas que se referem à classe abstrata `Pessoas` na base de dados. Como corrigir isso? Eu já possuo uma tabela específica para pessoas e preciso de outra específica para membros.

#### Classe abstrata:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Pessoas {

@Column
protected String nome;

@Column
protected String identidade;

@Column
protected String cpf;

@Column
protected String data_cadastro;

@Column
protected String naturalidade;

@Column
protected String nacionalidade;

@Column(name="data_nascimento")
protected String dataNascimento;

@Column(name="genero")
protected String sexo;

@Column(name = "estado_civil")
protected String estadoCivil;

@Column
protected String conjuge;

@Column(name = "data_casamento")
protected String dataCasamento;

@Column
protected String escolaridade;

@Column(name = "nome_pai")
protected String nomePai;

@Column(name = "nome_mae")
protected String nomeMae;

@Column(name = "data_batismo")
protected String dataBatismo;

@Column
protected String situacao;

@Column
protected String endereco;

@Column
protected String numero;

@Column
protected String bairro;

@Column
protected String cidadeEndereco;

@Column
protected String estadoEndereco;

@Column
protected String celular;

@Column
protected String telefone;

@Column
protected String email;

//Getter e Setters
```

#### Classe concreta:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_pessoas")
public class PessoasModel extends Pessoas {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id_pessoa;

public int getId_pessoa() {
    return id_pessoa;
}

public void setId_pessoa(int id_pessoa) {
    this.id_pessoa = id_pessoa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o uso da anotação @Inheritance na sua superclasse.

Exemplo:

```
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PESSOA")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) 
public abstract class Pessoa {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBRO")
public class Membro extends Pessoa{
    ...
}
```

Neste caso você tem uma tabela para Pessoa, apenas com os campos dos atributos definidos na própria classe ,e uma tabela para Membro, apenas com os atributos definidos na própria classe idem. Estas serão unidas pelo id definido na classe pessoa (JOINED).

Você pode explorar os outros dois 'Inheritance Type' do enum## Cabeçalhos ## para resolver outros casos que precise:

```
public enum InheritanceType { 

    /** A single table per class hierarchy. */
    SINGLE_TABLE, 

    /** A table per concrete entity class. */
    TABLE_PER_CLASS, 

    /** 
     * A strategy in which fields that are specific to a 
     * subclass are mapped to a separate table than the fields 
     * that are common to the parent class, and a join is 
     * performed to instantiate the subclass.
     */
    JOINED 
}
```

> [Referência Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance)

Comment: Obrigado man... vou dar uma estudada

Comment: Faz o teste com o primeiro exemplo na sua aplicação e posta aqui as dúvidas.